# How to make Reftex menu recursive (or nested)?

Tags: emacs, reftex

I have the fllowing lines in my .emacs:

```
(add-hook 'reftex-load-hook 'imenu-add-menubar-index)
(add-hook 'reftex-mode-hook 'imenu-add-menubar-index)
(global-set-key [down-mouse-3] 'imenu)
```

It produces a Reftex context menu whenever I press the mouse right button on a document. The problem is that the menu contains all the sections, subsection and subsubsections in a linear fashion.

I'd like this menu to show the sections in the document only and when I move the cursor on one of the sections, its subsections show up in a new menu and so on. (Similar to the menu in Orgmod.) This would be useful for large documents.

Comment: can `C-C =` help?

Comment: It says C-c = is undefined.

Comment: make sure to enable reftex-mode (`M-x reftex-mode`).

Comment: Thank you. I modified my question to make the point clear.